# Payment is not deducting when I use Apple Pay

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, payment, applepay

I am using react-native-apay Package for Apple Pay, Issue we are facing which is amount is not deducting from wallet.
This is the request which we are sending in requestPayment

```
requestData = {
        merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.dumy.pkg',
        supportedNetworks: ['mastercard', 'visa'],
        countryCode: 'SA',
        currencyCode: 'SAR',
        id: sessionId,
        paymentSummaryItems: [
          {
            amount: 100,
            label: 'dummy,
          }
        ],
      };
ApplePay.requestPayment(requestData)
            .then(paymentData => {
          
 ApplePay.complete(ApplePay.SUCCESS).then(() => {}).catch(){

})
```

After this process amount should be deduct from Card but its not happening.
Card is showing correct amount and card details on ApplePay modal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of that package. You should send Apple Pay token (paymentData) to your merchant provider to process the transaction. And also remember, Simulator always returns an empty string.